# Why disable interrupts in XV6 scheduler?

Tags: locking, scheduler, interrupt, osdev, xv6

For the sched() function (proc.c) in XV6

1. why must we disable interrupts when doing a context switch? Is it because if interrupts are enabled, the sched function can be repeatedly invoked?
2. Why must ncli (the depth of pushcli nesting) be equal to 1?

```c
   sched(void) {
      int intena;

      if(readeflags()&FL_IF)
        panic("sched interruptible");
      if(cp->state == RUNNING)
        panic("sched running");
      if(!holding(&ptable.lock))
        panic("sched ptable.lock");
      if(c->ncli != 1)
        panic("sched locks");

      intena = c->intena;
      swtch(&cp->context, &c->context);
      c->intena = intena;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. why must we disable interrupts when doing a context switch? Is it because if interrupts are enabled, the sched function can be repeatedly invoked?

Each task has state, which includes the state of the CPU and the state of various variables the OS uses to keep track of things (e.g. which task is currently running). The `switch()` function switches from one task's state to another; but it doesn't do this atomically. If an IRQ occurred while `switch()` is in the middle of switching from one task to another then the IRQ handler would see inconsistent state (e.g. the "which task is currently running" variable not matching the current virtual address space) which can/will lead to subtle bugs that are extremely difficult to reproduce (because you have to get the timing exactly right for the problem to happen) and extremely hard to find and fix.

Note that operating systems that support multiple CPUs can't rely on "IRQs disabled" to prevent reentrancy problems (e.g. disabling IRQs on one CPU won't prevent another CPU from calling `sched()` while it's already running). For this; XV6 (which does support multiple CPUs) uses a lock (the `ptable.lock`).

> 2. Why must ncli (the depth of pushcli nesting) be equal to 1?

From the CPU's perspective:

- one task causes `ncli` to be set to 1
- a task switch happens
- another task causes `ncli` to decremented to zero

From a task's perspective:

- the task causes `ncli` to be set to 1
- many task switches happen (while other tasks are given CPU time) until the task is given CPU time again
- the task causes `ncli` to decremented to zero

Both of these perspectives need to be compatible. For example, if one task causes `ncli` to be set to 2, then (after task switches) decrements `ncli` twice; then "from that task's perspective" it would be fine, but "from CPU's perspective" it would break (a different task would only decrement `ncli` once resulting in IRQs being disabled when they shouldn't be).

In other words, `ncli` must always be the same value. The value 1 was probably chosen because it's "good enough" for the majority of callers and using a higher value would add unnecessary overhead.